# Regular conditional Bayesian experiment

Tags: bayesian

In "Elements of Bayesian Statistics" (1990), Florens, Mouchart and Rolin describe two basic forms of reduction of a Bayesian experiment: Marginalization and Conditioning (Ch. 1). I don't understand the conditioning reduction. More precisely, i struggle with the definition of a *regular* conditional experiment. I would appreciate an explanation, if possible in measure-theoretic terms. Thanks

Comment: @Zen: [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzbZQLKx1ZTReUFzUURaLWV6QXc/edit?usp=sharing)'s part of a letter i wrote to Prof. Florens requesting him for an explanation of the definition of 'regular conditional experiment'. I go there in greater detail into what it is exactly that i don't understand. [Here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzbZQLKx1ZTRM2o3MkxMNkl0M00/edit?usp=sharing) are the relevant pages from the book. If you need further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: Florens et al.'s book has the distinction of being the first book to lay Bayesian statistics on rigorous, measure-theoretic foundations. There is only one other book on the market with the same rigorous approach to this subject, Schervish's Statistical Theory, but it is much less clear, imo, than Florens et al.'s, as implausibly as it may seem. Florens et al. is surely idiosyncratic, considering the fact that it's a break-through work, but i have seen it cited in published papers, so apparently some folks have managed to figure it out and i aspire to eventually count myself among them.

Comment: Regarding your question. It's a good one. The authors don't do as good a job explaining the conditioning reduction unambiguously as they do with the marginalization reduction. However, i feel pretty comfortable with the following interpretation of $\Pi^\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of the sample space $\left(S,\mathcal{S}\right)$. Then $\Pi^\mathcal{T}$ is a regular version of the conditional probability of $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S}$ conditional on $\mathcal{T}$ given $\Pi$.

Comment: In other words, $\Pi^\mathcal{T}$ is a transition from $\left(S,\mathcal{T}\right)$ to $\left(A\times S,\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S}\right)$, which satisfies the following condition. For every $D\in\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S}$ and every $E\in\mathcal{T}$, $\Pi\left(D\cap E\right)=\int_E\Pi^\mathcal{T}\left(t,D\right)\space P\left(dt\right)$, with $P$ being the predictive probability, defined in p. 27 as the restriction of $\Pi$ to the sample space.

Comment: P.S. By "transition" i meant what is elsewhere called a "[Markov kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_kernel&oldid=491600480)". "Transition" is the terminology employed in the book (p. 17).

Comment: @Zen: P.S. #2 By "$\Pi\left(D\cap E\right)$" i meant "$\Pi\left(D\cap\left(A\times E\right)\right)$".

Comment: Evan: are you sure? Isn't $\mathcal{T}$ a sub-sigma-field of $\mathcal{A}\vee\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: @Zen: Yes, i'm sure. There's also a version $\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{M}$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is an arbitrary sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S}$. If you can figure out the more general case, be my guest, but i think once the simpler case is cracked, the other case will be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a more general case with arbitrary $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{B}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{T}\subseteq\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S}$ and a combined conditional/marginal experiment

$$
\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}=\left(A\times S,\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S},\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}\right)
$$

(see "Combined Reductions" on pp. 53-54).

Define

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\Omega & := & A\times S \\
\Xi & := & \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{S} \\
\Gamma & := & \mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M} \\
\Gamma' & := & \left(\Omega,\Gamma\right) \\
\Delta_1 & := & \left(\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}\right)\otimes\left(\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}\right) \\
\Delta_1' & := & \left(\Omega\times\Omega,\Delta_1\right) \\
\Delta_2 & := & \left(\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}\right)\otimes\left(\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}\right) \\
\Delta_2' & := & \left(\Omega\times\Omega,\Delta_2\right)
\end{array}
$$

and define $X$ to be the function

$$
X:\Omega\rightarrow\left(\Omega\times\Omega\right),\hspace{10mm}X\left(\omega\right):=\left(\omega,\omega\right)
$$

Note that $X$ is a $\Gamma/\Delta_1$-measurable as well as $\Gamma/\Delta_2$-measurable.

$\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}$ is called *regular* iff $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}$ is regular (the book does not make it clear whether $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}$ should be assumed regular when $\mathcal{E}^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}$ is not regular) and there exist regular versions of $\mu^{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}_\mathcal{B\vee\mathcal{M}}$ and $P^{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}$.

If this is the case,

$$
\mu^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}\otimes P^{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}
$$

is a Markov kernel from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\Delta_1$ and for all $D\in\Delta_1$,

$$
\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega, X^{-1}(D)\right)=\left(\mu^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}\otimes P^{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\right)\left(\omega,D\right)\tag{1}
$$

for $\left[\Xi,\Pi_\mathcal{M}\right]$-almost every $\omega\in\Omega$. Write $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M},\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega,D\right)$ as a shorthand for $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega, X^{-1}(D)\right)$, $D\in\Delta_1$.

In the same vein,

$$
P^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\otimes \mu^{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}
$$

is a Markov kernel from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\Delta_2$ and for all $D\in\Delta_2$,

$$
\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega,X^{-1}(D)\right)=\left(P^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\otimes\mu^{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}\right)\left(\omega,D\right)\tag{2}
$$

for $\left[\Xi,\Pi_\mathcal{M}\right]$-almost every $\omega\in\Omega$. Write $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M},\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega,D\right)$ as a shorthand for $\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}\vee\mathcal{M}}\left(\omega, X^{-1}(D)\right)$, $D\in\Delta_2$.

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together constitute the rigorous interpretation of equations $1.4.16$ in Florens et al.'s book. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59148/reductions-of-bayesian-experiments-regular-conditional-experiment) for more on that.

$X$ is an embedding of $\Gamma'$ in $\Delta'_1$ in the sense that $X$ is injective and measurable and $\Gamma=X^{-1}\left(\Delta_1\right)$.

Moreover, from Doob's Functional Representation Lemma (Lemma 1.13 in Kallenberg's Foundations of Modern Probability (2002)), also known as The Factorisation Lemma, if $\left(H,\mathcal{B}\right)$ is a Borel space, then $f:\Omega\rightarrow H$ is $\Gamma/\mathcal{B}$-measurable iff there is some $\Delta_1/\mathcal{B}$-measurable function $h$ such that $f=h\circ X$.

Additionally, if we equip $\Gamma'$ with a probability measure $\phi$ (e.g. $\phi=\Pi$ or $\phi=\Pi^\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{B}\vee\mathcal{T}}\left(\omega,\cdot\right)$ for some fixed $\omega\in\Omega$) and equip $\Delta'_1$ with $X$'s distribution function, $\phi_X$, then $f$ and $h$ have the same distributions. Furthermore, if $\mathcal{B}$ is the standard Borel field on the extended real line, we have by the Substitution Lemma (Lemma 1.22 in Kallenberg's book)$^*$, that $f$ has an integral w.r.t. $\left(\Gamma',\phi\right)$ iff $h$ has an integral w.r.t. $\left(\Delta'_1,\phi_X\right)$ and in this case the values of the integrals are identical.

In like manner, $X$ is an embedding of $\Gamma'$ in $\Delta'_2$.

---

$(*)$ Actually, Theorem 1.6.12 in Ash's Probability and Measure Theory (2000) is more appropriate for the level of generality stated here.